# MockMvc test not reach the Controller

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockito, mockmvc

I've tried a lot but unfortunately without success. I don't understand why I can't reach my controller.I have to run this test via the standalone setup because I don't have a SpringBoot project.

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class HelpPageControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private HelpService helpService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(new HelpPageController())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void justATest() throws Exception {
        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/help/manuals?lang=de"));
        resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

This is my API that I'm trying to reach:

```
      @GetMapping("/help/manuals")
      public ResponseEntity<List<ManualResponseTO>> getManuals(@RequestParam String lang) {
       List<ManualResponseTO> manuals;
       manuals = this.helpService.getManuals(lang);
       return new ResponseEntity<>(manuals, HttpStatus.OK);
     }
```

Running the Test I get this answer:

[image]

When i go into the Debug-Mode I can see that the mockMvc is initialized, but I have also set a debug point in my controller, but this I can´t reach.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(HelpPageController.class)
public class HelpPageControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    ...
}
```

or

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(HelpPageController.class)
public class HelpPageControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private HelpPageController helpPageController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(helpPageController)
            .build();
    }

    ...
}
```

dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: At Both cases I got this exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a "@SpringBootConfiguration", you need to use "@ContextConfiguration" or "@SpringBootTest(classes=...)" with your test

Comment: What is your test dependency?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-test +
spring-test

Comment: is it possible to share your project to Github?

Comment: No, sorry I´m not allowed to share it

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I need a test *Context Configuration*.

**testContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

Now I am also mocking my *Service*. This is the code I need:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:testContext.xml")
public class HelpPageControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private HelpService helpService;

    @InjectMocks
    private HelpPageController helpPageController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(helpPageController)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void justATest() throws Exception {
        List<ManualResponseTO> manualResponseTOS = new ArrayList<>();
        when(helpService.getManuals("de")).thenReturn(manualResponseTOS);
        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/manuals?lang=de"));
        resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```